# Quarto rendering not updating charts or numbers

Tags: r, quarto

Good day everyone

I've been building a quarto document and running code chunks as I go along. I rendered the document and everything went well. The underlying data however in my df changed and as a result, the inline codes and charts in my quarto document, that are connected to my df should have changed, but they have not.

I find this behaviour strange as the charts and numbers in my environment are correct when I run the code chunks in R studio but the rendering of the .qmd results in old charts and numbers being displayed.

It appears that the rendering of the document is defaulting to an earlier rendering and not updating at all. See the side-by-side comparison that I have attached of the correct ggplot chart in R studio vs what that same chart renders to in pdf. What am I missing?

The same thing happens to inline code and any other number.  [image: studio vs rendered pdf]

My YAML is

```
---
title: "My paper"
subtitle: 'subtitle here'
date: '11 October 2023'
author: "Myself"
format:
  pdf:
    include-in-header:
      text: |
         \usepackage{typearea}
    toc: true
    number-sections: true
    colorlinks: true
    lof: true
    lot: true
    papersize: 'a4'
    code-line-numbers: true
    code-fold: true
    code-overflow: wrap
editor: visual
---
```

Comment: Where in your document do you read in the data? When you build the document that happens in a new process unlike when you run chunks in RStudio. Are you sure the document is reading in the updated data?

Comment: @MrFlick you're right. Was a simple mistake on my part. The chunk I was looking at was reading the old data.